# Is there a tool to reassemble C# partial class files into one single class source code file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, partial-classes

Is there a tool that can reassemble C# partial class files into one single class source code file? Sure I could do by hand, but if such a tool exists, that would make it much easier. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: If you do this, what's the point of partial classes?

Comment: @Randy: There isn't a point. He/she is probably trying to fix what someone else called "refactoring".

Comment: Nobody writes a tool that does Ctrl+x, Ctrl+v given how hard it is to do it always correctly.  Impossible to compete with the tool between your ears.

Answer (score 2):

[Red Gate .NET Reflector.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but as said i need code to be like source code not name mangled.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflector.

Variable names won't be so beautiful but it will give you what you want.

Comment: Just give it a shot, it gave all original names when I just tried. See if it works for you.

Comment: It should use the original variable names as long as you haven't obfuscated your code. You have to do the "name manging" yourself if you feel the need. Obviously, you can just compile and work on a Debug build that you haven't run through an obfuscator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any such tool available, 
may be you can try is to write a macro.